# length of sub string based on user input

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

User is not allowed to enter anything less than 3 char. I am after something where I can get sub string with 2 char less or minimum of 3 char length. something like

```
`Tes -> Tes
Test -> Tes
TestN -> Tes
TestNa -> Test
TestNam -> TestN
TestName -> TestNa`
```

I have tried the below but it doesnt work when the passed in string is 3 or 4 char, it will cut into 3 into 1 and 4 in to 2 chars the number but cant think of a better way to achieve the above

```
'name like SUBSTRING (+ @TestName,1,len(@TestName)-2)`
```

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just a little CASE baked into the expression

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([String] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Tes')
,('Test')
,('TestN')
,('TestNa')
,('TestNam')
,('TestName')

Select *
      ,Left(String,case when Len(String)<=4 then 3 else Len(String)-2 end)
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
String      (No column name)
Tes         Tes
Test        Tes
TestN       Tes
TestNa      Test
TestNam     TestN
TestName    TestNa
```

Comment: That worked, thanks mate! I wish I thought about it a bit more.

Comment: @s-a-n I suspect you were just over-thinking it.  Happens to all of us :)

Comment: I think I surely was. Thanks for help! :-)